# do the core servers in Neo4j implement the leaders in a multilayer protocol?

Tags: neo4j, database-replication

I am studying replication protocols while developing a little database in Neo4j. While reading the documentation I have read the definition "core servers" and to me it seems that they are exactly the same as leaders in a multilayer system. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core servers handle write transactions.
A core can have one of the following roles : `leader` or `follower`.

In a cluster there can be **only one leader** (and so, tere are many followers)

Comment: If a node handles the writes doesn't this mean that the node it's a leader? What are the specific duties of a leader node in Neo4j?

Comment: A write is validated by a consensus of core nodes, but the entry point is the leader.

Comment: Sorry i am not following you. What do you mean by entry point?

Comment: All write requests go only to the leader, as the leader is the only one of the core nodes allowed to process writes, and as logisima mentioned a write is validated by a consensus of the core nodes. If the leader goes down (or a cluster spins up for the first time) an election is held between the core nodes to determine which one is made leader. So, any core node can become the leader, but there is always only a single leader at a time, and only the leader can process write queries.

Comment: @InverseFalcon What if we need to distribute geographically our datacenter and we need at least one node per datacenter to be the leader and to accept writes? Would it be possible?

Comment: you can distribute your Neo4j cluster on multiple datacenter, there is no problem, and you can have core servers on each DC. Check the documentation here : https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.3/clustering/causal-clustering/multi-data-center/design/
But you will have only one leader across all core servers.
Otherwise you can make one Neo4j cluster on each DC, and make by yourself a sync mecanism between them (be careful at your data consistency in this case)